# Stuck trying to make this tensorflow script work

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to move my scikit-learn python script into tensorflow code. Keep getting stuck with errors. Please help!

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import tensorflow as tf

    # read csv
    df = pd.read_csv("/Downloads/iris-2.csv", header=0)

    # get header names as array
    features = list(df.columns.values)
    label = features.pop()
    classes = len(df[label].unique())

    # encode target
    X = df[features]
    y = df[label]

    # convert feature headers into tf
    for index,value in enumerate(features):
        features[index] = tf.feature_column.numeric_column(value)

    # initialize classifier
    classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
        feature_columns=features,
        hidden_units=[10, 10],
        n_classes=classes)

    # train the classifier
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(X), y))
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000).repeat().batch(0)
    data = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    classifier.train(input_fn=lambda:data,steps=3)
    predictions = classifier.predict([5.1,3.0,4.2,1.2])
    print(predictions)
```

Latest error I'm stuck on is:

```
ValueError: Passed Tensor("dnn/head/weighted_loss/Sum:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) should have graph attribute that is equal to current graph <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x10dd9a190>.
```

Here's the dataset I'm using: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/curran/a08a1080b88344b0c8a7/raw/d546eaee765268bf2f487608c537c05e22e4b221/iris.csv

Comment: Has a temp directory been created with Graph/Checkpoints in it? Have you tried deleting that?

Comment: Hmm.. there doesn't seem to be any file in the temp directory

Comment: Try specifying one when you create the DNNClassifier. 

Take a look at my sample here: https://github.com/lmoroney/myblogcode/blob/master/nnforblog.py

If you ever change the shape of the NN, it gets confused when trying to read the graph back from checkpoints, so it's always good to clear out the temp directory should you do so. As you haven't specified one here, I'm not sure where it's reading from.

Answer (score 0):

The input tensor (variables *data* and *dataset*) cannot be precomputed. They need to be computed inside the function passed to *input_fn* in the call to *train*  so that the tensors are in the graph that the Estimator (*classifier*) creates during the call to *train()*. So for your last block you could use:

```
# train the classifier
def my_input_fn():
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(X), y))
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000).repeat().batch(0)
    return dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
classifier.train(input_fn=my_input_fn, steps=3)
predictions = classifier.predict([5.1,3.0,4.2,1.2])
print(predictions)
```